# How to update row with concurrency control using EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I've a table "Orders" with columns: "Id", "ProductId", "Status", "Version".

"Version" is incremented with 1 after every changing of the row.
This column is for control concurrency of several users changes.

For example, I read an order with Id=3 and Version=7. When I update it, I must be sure that nobody has changed this row yet.
By SQL, I would write such script:

```
UPDATE Orders
SET Status = 'completed', Version = Version + 1
WHERE Id = 3 AND Version = 7
```

How can I write the same code by EF Core without using SQL command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Just mark `Version` as a [Concurrency Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations) and its pre-update value will be used in the `WHERE` clause of any update. EG

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .Property(o => o.Version)
            .IsConcurrencyToken(true);
```

For a change like

```
var order = ...
order.Status = "Completed";
order.Version += 1;
db.SaveChanges();
```

The UPDATE will look something like this:

```
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  UPDATE [Events] SET [Status] = @p0, [Version] = @p1
  WHERE [Id] = @p2 AND [Version] = @p3;
  SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

And if the `Version` has changed 0 rows will be affected and EF will throw an
`DbUpdateConcurrencyException` indicating a [concurrency conflict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency).

You can also use server-side incrementing for the concurrency token with additional configuration, or by using a provider-specific type like SQL Server's [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).