# C# ef-core -> what is the end result of calling savechanges for multiple instances with potenial DbUpdateConcurrencyException for one instance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, concurrency, savechanges

I have a ef-core + sql application with a model named "indicator". It has a ConcurrencyToken set to property "TimeStampUpdated".

In a long running task I read all indicators that must be marked for repeat with code:

```
var indicatorsToRepeat = await careOrganisationMessagingDbContext.Indicators
.Where(ind => ind.StateRepeat == true && 
   ind.TimestampRepeat != null && 
   EF.Functions.DateDiffSecond(ind.TimestampRepeat, timeStampNow) >= 0) 
.ToListAsync();

if (indicatorsToRepeat != null && indicatorsToRepeat.Any())
{
   foreach (Indicator indicator in indicatorsToRepeat)
   {
      indicator.MustRepeatNow = true;
      indicator.TimestampRepeat = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds((int)indicator.RepeatInterval);
   }
                        
   try
   {
      await careOrganisationMessagingDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
   catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
   {
      // Do nothing
   }
}
```

This task runs the repeat detection every 2 seconds and never changes "TimeStampUpdated". In potention one or more of the list of "indicatorsToRepeat" could be outdated by the shoot and forget tasks that do update indicators "State" as well as "TimeStampUpdated".

I'm not interested in detecting if indicator.DetectMustRepeatNow() saving fails. The Update must overrule and detectRepeats may not overwrite changes made by Update tasks. To achieve this I first imagined sql query with Where clause including "TimeStampUpdate" matching the old value. But this is not possible in ef-core. So I decided to use the ConcurrencyToken for "TimeStampUpdated". So update would fail if the value changed.

The real question:

I was wondering what would happen if I have 10 indicators to savechanges to where the third could not be updated due to concurrency (TimeStampUpdated changed between read and save).

Would the others (1..2 and 4..10) be updated or does the exception occure right after the third? I red this article below among others but cannot find the answer.

[How to update row with concurrency control using EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67942231/how-to-update-row-with-concurrency-control-using-ef-core)

Thanks in advance for answering my question,
Edwin

Comment: When EF saves a DbContext, it includes a where clause that matches the expected concurrency value for each modified entity.  If that returns 0 rows updated, it throws the DbUpdateConcurrencyException.  All entities are updated as part of a transaction, so in the case of an exception, none of the entities will be persisted.

Comment: Dear Neil, Thank you for your answer. So to avoid misunderstanding: Any call to dbContext.SaveChanges() or dbContext.SaveChangesAsync() is considered a transaction including all tracked changes as a set? What about tracked changes for different models/tables?

Comment: Can you propose a solution to minimize my round trips to the persistance layer so I do not have to save each indicator separately? Is there a way to add a condition to each indicator in a list of indicators to save, allowing it to 0 rows updated without raising an exception?

Comment: All changes within a single DbContext are updated as a single transaction.  The general idea is that you will catch the exception, reload the DbContext from the database again, modify it to match your new changes, and attempt the SaveChanges again.

Comment: Thank you Neil. In the meanwhile I chose the approach you suggest.